# Get a copy of a live Wordpress site to work on localhost with Xampp on Linux

Tags: linux, wordpress, xampp

What I'm trying to achieve is to have a local version on my Wordpress site on Linux in order to work locally offline.

So I downloaded my Wordpress site using Filezilla and place it in the htdocs directory. On my Mac it works, I can see the errors to fix in order to adapt it locally. However on Linux it doesn't seem to work the same way. With the same version on my site, instead of going on localhost, it redirects to my live site, which is odd given that everything has been done in the exact same way on the Mac.

Then I tried to reverse the process by installing a fresh copy of Wordpress and copying my custom theme and its plugins (WPML, Custom Field Pro and so on) in their right directories. The thing is I can fix the problem with my first method but with the latter it's getting tricky.

It has to work on Linux which is the machine that will be used in the office.

What do you guys suggest me to do from there? Any information you need please let me know.

Thank you very much in advance,
Julien

[EDIT]
I have changed the first and second row of wp-options in the DB to localhost instead of live URL.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to look in database, Table: wp_options. 
You would see siteurl and home. 
Then you should change to localhost.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way than manually copying the site is using a plugin called Duplicator, which you can find more info on below:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

This plugin makes it vastly easier to duplicate entire WordPress sites to local machines, without worrying about manually copying the database, core files, themes, etc.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!

Comment: If you're happy with my answer, could you mark it as answered please? Thanks! :)

Comment: I need to test it first, no idea if it's going to solve my problem to run my WP site locally on Linux.

Comment: No worries, keep me posted.

Answer (score 0):

go to **phpmyadmin > your database > wp_options**  check the first two rows of **wp_options** table it should be **siteurl** and **home** you'll see your live site url there replace it with your localhost directory link.

`http://example.com` change it to `localhost/yoursite`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already did that, but I only changed it to http://localhost. I try the variants.

Comment: localhost acts as /public_html/ directory, if you put your web files in htdocs root then chaange url to just **localhost**, if you have created any directory in htdocs then u have to include directory path also after localhost **localhost/[directory]**

Comment: Thanks for this enlightenment Asalan.